# Method for printing out an arraylist

Tags: printing, arraylist

I have made an Arraylist of assistants (String name, int salary)

i would like to create a method that will print out all of the assistants, no matter how many we add to the list.

i want to be able to call the method from my run file when time is due.

how would i gå about making that method ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ArrayList definition to be: ArrayList asstList

```
private void PrintAssistnatList() {
    for(Assistant asst:asstList) {
        System.out.println("Name: "+asst.name+" salary: "+salary);
    }
}
```